# How to use chip XL6007E1 to build a boost ciruit?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, stm32, boost, microchip

My ciruit:
[image: problem ciruit]

Input: 3.7V
But no matter how I adjust the potentiometer, the voltage did not rise.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here: -

[image]

The most obvious problem is that the enable pin (EN) is floating. Try connecting it to Vin as per the data sheet: -

[image]

Other potential issues?

- Why haven't you got 220 uF on the output like the data sheet suggests?
- What output voltage are you trying to achieve?
- What is SW1 all about?
- Why haven't you got the recommended input capacitance?